# Past Simple for non-sequential events

Tags: meaning, past-simple

Are these sentences idiomatic; do they imply the order of events?

> It did not arrive yesterday when I checked.

Is it idiomatic? Do we understand that the checking happened after the non-arrival?

> Yesterday, when I checked, it did not arrive.

Do we understand that the checking came after the non-arrival like in the first sentence?

OR am I obliged to use past perfect

Comment: But why ? There must be a reason

Comment: We can say it did not arrive yesterday so why cant we add when I checked to this sentence

Comment: Your first example isn't idiomatic. This is one of those less common contexts where you almost certainly *need* to use a Perfect verb form: *It **had not arrived** yesterday when I checked.* But if a competent native speaker used the "do-support" version above, we would have to assume some relatively lengthy checking process *during which time* the checker hoped/expected that it would arrive (and for some reason arrival would *only* be expected during that checking process). Note that the existing tense choice would work perfectly well with *It did not **work** yesterday when I checked*.

Comment: So why does it fit with work and not with arrive

Comment: Because the context there is that the speaker needs to perform the check to find out whether or not it works. It's also possible to say *It **was not working** yesterday when I checked,* which *doesn't* have that implication. Presumably that difference arises from the fact that ***working*** is a "continuous state", whereas ***arriving*** is a "time-specific event".

Comment: I don't think the irrelevant negation is doing you any favours here. Consider instead *It **[had] arrived** yesterday when I checked.* I can't easily imagine a context where *It had worked yesterday when I checked* would make sense, but you should be able to see a possible difference between *It **worked** yesterday when I checked* and *It **was working** yesterday when I checked.*

Comment: So when I checked comes first that is why it does not work with arrive .So why when I checked comes first ?because of when

Comment: Not really - I don't think it's useful here to think in terms of "which comes first". Focus on the fact that ***arriving*** happens at a specific point in time, and ***checking*** in this context would also normally be an "instant" action that doesn't continue over time. But ***working*** is usually a "continuous state", not an "action". That's where the difference lies.

Comment: can we deduct that 2 instant  verbs  for example receive and check can't go  together with past simple .We can't say I did not receive on Monday it when I checked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151008/discussion-between-yves-lefol-and-fumblefingers).

Answer (score 1):

Neither is idiomatic. They suggest either that the “it” arrived **while** the speaker was checking or that the “it” arrived immediately **upon** the checking and **as a result** of the checking.

The past perfect is the only way to go here.

Comment: Why do they suggest that the it arrived while I was checking or after

Comment: Is the Past Perfect *absolutely* necessary here: "*It **did not arrive** when I checked yesterday*"? The Past Perfect fits here, but I'm not sure discarding the Past Simple is 100% correct.

Comment: the payment of this order didn't arrive I didn't even check it .In this case  past simple fits why?Is it because both actions are simultaneous